# SQLAlchemy weird threading behavior

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy

Consider the following sample code using Python 3.6.5 and SQLAlchemy 1.2.7

```
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.exc import OperationalError
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session, Session

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///threading_sqlalchemy.db")
base = declarative_base(engine)
smaker = sessionmaker(engine)
scopedmaker: scoped_session = scoped_session(smaker)

dblock = threading.Lock()


class Key(base):
    __tablename__ = "Key"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Integer, nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    taken = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Key id={self.id}, value={self.value}, taken={self.taken}>"


try:
    Key.__table__.drop()
    # this is also quite funny, if the table doesn't exist it throws:
    # sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Key
    # when there is literally a sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError
except OperationalError:
    pass
base.metadata.create_all()


def gen_keys(n):
    print(f"made in {threading.current_thread()}")
    with dblock:
        session: Session = scopedmaker()
        session.bulk_save_objects([Key(value=i * 100) for i in range(0, n)])
        session.commit()


def take_keys(n):
    print(f"used in {threading.current_thread()}")
    with dblock:
        session: Session = scopedmaker()
        keys = session.query(Key).filter(Key.taken == False).limit(n).all()
        for key in keys:
            key.taken = True
        print(keys)
        session.commit()


def take_keys_2(n):
    print(f"used in {threading.current_thread()}")
    with dblock:
        session: Session = scopedmaker()
        keys = session.query(Key).filter(Key.taken == False).limit(n).all()
        for key in keys:
            key.taken = True
        session.commit()
        print(keys)


gen_keys(100)

# take_keys works just as expected
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for _ in range(0, 5):
        executor.submit(take_keys, 10)

# take_keys_2 breaks, raises following error
# >>> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.
# >>> The object was created in thread id 12340 and this is thread id 4312
# according to the console log, 12340 is one of the ThreadPoolExecutor threads, and 4312 is the main thread
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for _ in range(0, 5):
        executor.submit(take_keys_2, 10)
```

I just have a really simple class `Key` that has a value and can be marked as `taken`, think of something like a giveaway where you wouldn't want to distribute the same one to different potential customers. I used this to test for race conditions which do exist and forced me to use a lock on the database access, no big deal, I can live with that.

What I really don't understand is why `take_keys` works, but `take_keys_2` breaks when the only difference between them is the position of the `print(keys)`statement. Especially because in the non-functional example the error message seems to be that I'm using the created objects in the wrong thread (I'm not, I just use it after `session.commit()` in the same thread that created it.

If anyone could shed some light on why this happens, I'd be glad.

Comment: About `Key.__table__.drop()` and the "funny" exception: [use `checkfirst=True`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#creating-and-dropping-database-tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I don't have all the details, but enough to make some sense out of your situation. [Threading support in SQLite](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html#threading-pooling-behavior) has not been great. Because of that SQLAlchemy's pooling behaviour defaults to either `SingletonThreadPool` if using an in-memory database, or `NullPool` if using a file. The latter means no pooling at all, or in other words a connection is always opened and closed as requested.

The position of the `print()` matters because the above call to `session.commit()` expires all database loaded state of objects in the session. So in order to print the list of keys, which ends up calling their `__repr__`, SQLAlchemy has to refetch the state of each object. If you add `echo=True` to your call to `create_engine()`, this becomes apparent.

After all that your `session` in `take_keys_2` is holding a connection with an open transaction. This is where it gets a bit muddy: when the function exits, the `session` goes out of scope and that means that the connection held by it is eventually returned to the pool. But the pool is a `NullPool`, so it finalizes and closes the connection and discards it. The finalization means rolling back any open transaction and that's what's failing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Work/sqlalchemy/lib/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 705, in _finalize_fairy
    fairy._reset(pool)
  File "~/Work/sqlalchemy/lib/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 876, in _reset
    pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
  File "~/Work/sqlalchemy/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 457, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 140683561543424 and this is thread id 140683635291968
```

The finalization is performed in a "dummy" thread during interpreter shutdown, instead of the worker, since the connection was left lingering.

If for example you add a call to `session.rollback()` after `print(keys)`:

```
def take_keys_2(n):
    ...
    with dblock:
        ...
        session.commit()
        print(keys)
        session.rollback()
```

[the connection is returned to the pool explicitly](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#session-rollback), and `take_keys_2` works as well. Another option is to use `expire_on_commit=False` so that no additional queries are needed after the commit in order to print the representation of the `Key` objects:

```
def take_keys_2(n):
    with dblock:
        session: Session = scopedmaker(expire_on_commit=False)
        ...
```